# Same log message keeps on printing to debug.log file thousand of times

Tags: php, plugin-development, debug, wp-debug, logging

So i was debugging my PHP code while working with Wordpress site by writing to debug.log with error_log($message) or trigger_error($message).

My message in these log statements keeps on printing thousand of times in debug.log file from a same single statement declared in functions.php (for example purpose here i am logging from themes's functions.php which results in same issue of multiple printing though i was debugging from some snippet plugin)

Accordingly to check if this issue is caused by my code their in functions.php or snippet plugin being called multiple times i tried logging wih different mechanism [chrome console log & chrome browser alert], result was php debug log message was printed multiple times though chrome console log & chrome browser alert was only one time. So i believe my code is not running multiple times but debug log messages as printed by error_log or trigger_error is printed multiple times & keeps on printing thousand of times.

So i thought it could be due to my local development enviroment than i tried same thing in a fresh wordpress installation in a real environment, same thing happened. So found no solution/explaination to it yet.

***MY THEME'S functions.php WITH ALL TESTED CODE:***

```
.
.
.
//continuously keeps on printing in debug.log (many times)
$debug_log = "DEBUG-debug log";
trigger_error($debug_log);
//OR
error_log($debug_log);

//prints only one time in chrome console
$debug_console = "DEBUG-console";
echo "<script>console.log('$debug_console');</script>";

//alerts only one time in chrome
$debug_alert = "DEBUG-alert";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$debug_alert');</script>";
```

***MY debug.log FILE IS LIKE THIS:***

```
[14-Jan-2019 01:05:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:05:51 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:05:51 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:05:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:05:55 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:05:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:04 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:25 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:26 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:26 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:27 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:29 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:31 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:31 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:31 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:32 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:06:47 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:07:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:07:17 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:07:29 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:07:31 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:07:32 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:07:47 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2019 01:08:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  DEBUG-debug log in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 15
```

***EDIT: Question clarity***
To be clear i want to say Log prints multiple times (& keeps printing thousand of times) each time i load a page (so 1 page load -> continuously multiple repeated log from a single log statement in functions.php)

***EDIT: Checked disabling WordPress Heartbeat***
So as hinted i tried disabling Wordpress Heartbeat by adding piece of code i found googling to disable Heartbeat in Wordpress (will check it later whether needed or not) in functions.php at the top..but still getting those log messages multiple times in single page load.

***HEARTBEAT CODE ADDED TO functions.php:***

```
add_action( 'init', 'stop_heartbeat', 1 );
function stop_heartbeat() {
    wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
}
```

***EDIT: Checked AJAX Calls***
So as hinted, I monitored all network calls to my server through chrome developer options...their are no network calls post a page is fully loaded (page loaded with get/post html + assets network calls) so no Ajax Requests to the server after page is loaded.

Comment: functions.php is run every time anyone visits a page on your website. So yes, it's going to get logged a lot.

Comment: Sorry i was bit unclear..i mean to say everytime i load page it prints multiple times (& keeps printing thousand of times).

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Yes i am admin to the site logged in as admin...and only i am using it via local developmenet environment (local by flywheel)

Answer (score 1):

OK, as far as I understand, you've put this code:

```
$debug_log = "DEBUG-debug log";
trigger_error($debug_log);
//OR
error_log($debug_log);
```

directly in your `functions`php` file.

It means, that this code will be executed (so new log item will be added to log file) every time the `functions.php` file is loaded - so during every request to your WP.

It means, that every time someone views your page, there will be new log item added.

But... That's not all... If you're logged in, then WP sends Heartbeat requests. They will also result in new log items.

There are not so many log items logged with the same time in your log, so IMHO it's unlikely that they are printed in the same request.

PS. JS won't be executed during AJAX calls, so you won't see them multiple times.

Comment: So now i have added piece of code i found on internet to disable Heartbeat in Wordpress (will check it later whether needed or not) in functions.php at the top..but still getting those log messages multiple times in single page load.

Comment: Are there any AJAX requests on your site?

Comment: So i monitored network calls through chrome developer options to my web server...their are no network calls post a page is fully loaded (page loaded with get/post html + assets network calls)

Comment: Sir can you try it yourself printing log though from functions.php on your available environment with a fresh wordpress installation and as mentioned in original question i actually tried this and got the same results even with fresh wordpress installation on real server. So i believe nothing wrong with the user code/settings.

Comment: Are you the only one, who is opening that site?

Comment: Yes its only me who has access & visiting the site

Comment: @UtsavMadaan add var_dump of $_SERVER to that log. You’ll know what requests are causing the logs.

Comment: Ok so i did that logs printed with $_SERVER string representation very lesser times as compared to the logs which i printed for testing..now just printing only 3-4 times per request with $_SERVER dump with request origin/uri coming from frontend page, cron & ajax. Don't know what to do..will introspect it properly after some days having very less time for the project and will update it here. Thanks anyways.

Comment: So you've answered your own question - there are no multliple logs per request. AJAX is another request (and apparently there is an AJAX call on your page) and CRON is another request (and WP makes some CRON requests in the background during page visit) - everything is just fine and exactly how it is supposed to be.

Comment: No sir problem is not solved because logs are way more when logging just a random text as shown in the original question (small random text logged & it was printed many of times & keeps on printing), neither i am using any external theme for now...will find out the cause in some days and will update it here...but its strange when i log $_SERVER it logs just 4-5 times per request..but when random text it just keeps logging